# Order objects by invoice number using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Ruby I can sort some objects by invoice number in descending order like:

```
@app.sample_sales.sort_by {|sale| -sale.payload['invoice_number'].to_i }
```

However I can't quite get it to work using Rails:

```
@app.sample_sales.order("payload->'invoice_number' desc")
```

I've also tried:

```
@app.sample_sales.order("payload->'invoice_number::integer' desc")
```

---

Models

```
#sample_app.rb
class SampleApp < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sample_sales, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
#sample_sale.rb
class SampleSale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sample_app
end
```

Comment: Can you add your models where associations are defined? 

Comment: @brcebn sure. Added and amended `sales` method to `sample_sales`.

Comment: Good! What about « payload » association? 

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. Here is a good one:

```rb
@app.sample_sales.joins(:payload).order('payload.invoice_number desc')
```

I might update this answer when you've shared your model's associations.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to return a `SampleSale::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` object where I'm looking to return a `SampleSale::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`

Comment: It’s fine.  you should be able to call another « where » clause on it. 